# setOnItemClickListner for ImageView in ListView

Tags: android, listview

MyActivity contains a `ListView` with two `TextViews` and an `ImageView`.

How to `setOnClickListner` for that `ImageView` for each `listItem` ?

**Code of listView's Adapter:**

```
public class eProjectAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<eProjectDetails> {

private  ArrayList<eProjectDetails> arrayList;
private Context context;
public eProjectAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<eProjectDetails> al) {
    super(context,0,al);
    this.context = context;
    arrayList=al;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View currentView=convertView;
    if(currentView==null)
        currentView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);


     TextView tv1 = (TextView)  currentView.findViewById(R.id.project_name);
     TextView tv2 = (TextView) currentView.findViewById(R.id.project_hrs);
     TextView tv3 = (TextView) currentView.findViewById(R.id.income_tv);


        eProjectDetails pd = arrayList.get(position);
        tv1.setText(pd.getName());


       tv2.setText("Hours Spent : "+Integer.toString(pd.getHours()));
        tv3.setText("Income earned : $"+pd.getRate()*pd.getHours());
        if(pd.getLead()) {
            ImageView img = (ImageView) currentView.findViewById(R.id.edit_img);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.edit);
            img.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.reqBlue));
        }
    return currentView;

}
}
```

Comment: show your listview's adapter

Comment: @MeosCoder adapter code added :)

Comment: What are you actually asking? You've set two other things on the `ImageView` already. Why is the `OnClickListener` different?

Answer (score 2):

Try setOnClickListener for it:

```
        img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //todo
            }
        });
```